# Ms Fakes Stub:Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.FakesDelegates.Func<>

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, microsoft-fakes

I'm using the Microsoft Fakes framework. Somehow I'm stuck with this error. The line that throws is `return myAccount`.

```
IEnumerable<Account> myAccount = new List<Account>()
{
    new Account { MemberId = "TestMemberID01", FirstName="TestFirstName1", LastName="TestLastName1"},
    new Account { MemberId = "TestMemberID02", FirstName="TestFirstName2", LastName="TestLastName2"}
    new Account { MemberId = "TestMemberID03", FirstName="TestFirstName3", LastName="TestLastName3"}
 };

var stubMemberAccountService = new StubIMemberAccountService(); 

stubMemberAccountService.GetMemberInfoStringNullableOfDateTimeStringStringStringString = (input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6) =>
{
    return myAccount;
};
```

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 
>   'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.FakesDelegates.Func>' 
>   because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What is the type of `GetMemberInfoStringNullableOfDateTimeStringStringStringString`?

Comment: And for the second error, please edit and add the generic type to the error...

Comment: Thanks so much Nate!
Here is the method signature before I faked it:
    public IEnumerable<Account> GetMemberInfo(String memberId, DateTime? DOB, String accountType, String fName, String lName, String ssn)